# Как в JS из полученный через ajax массива собрать таблицу и вывести ее на страницу

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

я новичок , и не совсем понимаю как сделать задание , которое мне выдали на курсах.
У меня есть два файла 1-й index.html --> сама страницу + ajax запрос и 2-й --> some.php где находится обработчик.
Суть задания заключается в :

1. Ajax запрос должен возвращать json-объект со структурой {"success":1,"results":[]}
2. В js из полученный через ajax массива нужно собрать таблицу и вставить в страницу.

Заранее спасибо!

1-й файл index.html

```
<html>
<head>
         <style  type="text/css" media="screen"> 
        ul  li { 
        list-style-type:none; 
        } 
     </style>
</head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
    <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="5">
    <input type="text" name= "bdate" class="bdate"> <br>
    <button class="otpravka">Poisk</button>



<script>
    $(document).ready (function () {
            $("button.otpravka").on("click", function() {
                var bdateValue =  $('input.bdate').val();


                $.ajax({                                                                                
                  method: "POST",
                  url: "some.php",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: { bdate:bdateValue},
                  success: function(response)
            {

                    
                    alert(response);

           }
                })


                 $('input.bdate').val(); 


            })
    })



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

2-й файл some.php

```
<?php 

    $name=$_POST['bdate'];

                $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fp;charset=utf8','root');
                $sql = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE firt_name LIKE :n OR last_name LIKE :n1 OR bdate LIKE :n2 ");
                $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute(["n"=>$name,"n1"=>$name,"n2"=>$name]);
            while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $output = '
    <tr>
      <td>'.$row['firt_name'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['last_name'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['bdate'].'</td>
    </tr>'; 
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не вполне поняли что от вас требуется. Зачем html для таблицы вы формируете в php? и зачем потом html текст сериализировать?

Запрос к БД я не проверял, но будем считать что правильный. Из php вам надо возвращать только сам массив. Типа такого

```
<?php 

  $output = Array(); // это ваш массив для возврата в js
  $output['success']=0; // Пока не получили результат, тут будет отрицательный код обработки
  $results = Array();  // это массив с результатами запроса 
  // Запрос к БД я никак не проверял
  $name=$_POST['bdate'];
  $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fp;charset=utf8','root');
  $sql = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE firt_name LIKE :n OR last_name LIKE :n1 OR bdate LIKE :n2 ");
  $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
  if($query->execute(["n"=>$name,"n1"=>$name,"n2"=>$name]))
    $output['success']=1; // Если смогли запросить данные, значит ставим 1 в рез. обработки
  while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    array_push($results,$row); // добавляем полученный столбец в массив результатов
  }    
  $output['results'] = $results; // помещаем массив результатов в возвращаемый массив
  echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Далее в js (в обработчике jquery.ajax) обрабатывать полученный результат:

```
$.ajax({                                                                                
                  method: "POST",
                  url: "some.php",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: { bdate:bdateValue},
                  success: function(response)
            {
                    $("#mytable").empty(); // таблицу результатов предварительно надо очистить. (обратите внимание. в балицу добавлен id!)
                    if(response['success']==0) return; // если success=0 выходим
                    var res = response['results'];
                    $.each(res,function(i,row) { // цикл по строкам
                        var newline=''; //сюда накопим html строки
                        $.each(row,function(i,val) { //цикл по столбцам
                          newline+='<td>'+val+'</td>'; // добавляем ячейку со значением
                        });
                        $("#mytable").append('<tr>'+newline+'</tr>'); // добавляем в таблицу строку
                    });
           }
                })
```

Comment: Спасибо, видимо я действительно не верно понял то , что мне нужно сделать